# How can I modify get_price_html to create custom price display for on sale items

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

this is my first question on Stack Overflow...
I am modifying a WooCommerce website for a client. What they want is for all items which have a sale prices to display a red dot next to the sale price.
I have located the public function 'get_price_html' in abstract-wc-product.php:

```
    /**
     * Returns the price in html format.
     *
     * @param string $deprecated Deprecated param.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_price_html( $deprecated = '' ) {
        if ( '' === $this->get_price() ) {
            $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', '', $this );
        } elseif ( $this->is_on_sale() ) {
            $price = wc_format_sale_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $this, array( 'price' => $this->get_regular_price() ) ), wc_get_price_to_display( $this ) ) . $this->get_price_suffix();
        } else {
            $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $this ) ) . $this->get_price_suffix();
        }

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this );
    }
```

I have figured out that if I modify the 'elseif ( $this->is_on_sale()' section, I can do what I want, and this works, but only when I modify and upload the core version of abstract-wc-product.php, which I don't want to do.

I have child theme going, and in my child theme directory, I have copied abstract-wc-product.php into the following folder structure:

woocommerce/includes/abstracts

This isn't working, so I have also tried to copy the function above into my functions.php file, to see if this overrides the core version.

Neither of these is working - can anybody help with how to do this, please?

Thank you!

Stuart

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you've found out, you can't copy Class files. They do not work like templates and you cannot copy the functions, as that will not work either. You need to use `add_filter` to hook into the `woocommerce_get_price_html` filter. However, why not use CSS to target the Sale price and add your dot in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is in `return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', $price, $this );`

Check the doc here about how to use filters in WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

In your case, I believe you can achieve your goal with this function below - not tested!!

```
 function custom_sale_price( $price, $product ){
    
        if( $product->is_on_sale() ){
             
             return '<span class="red-dot"></span>' . $price; 
         }
  
         return $price;  
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_sale_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks very much Tami - that works a treat!

Comment: Awesome! Upvote the answer if you can for others :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use CSS, here's how you do it:

```
/* Here's the woocommerce filter. Then we use a static function (anonymous function) to pass the two arguments that the original filter passes.*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', static function( $price, $product ) {
    // Now we check to see if the product is onsale.
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) :
        // Change this to whatever worked for you when you modified core files.
        $price = wc_format_sale_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ), wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    endif;

// Return the $price. This is here in the event the product that is passed isn't on sale. 
return $price;

}, 10, 2 );
```

This goes into your child theme `functions.php`.

Comment: Hi disinfor - I hadn't thought of doing it in CSS, but I've got the custom function working thanks to you and Tami, so thank you! I can see you've done a static function too, so I've been reading up about those too - plenty to learn!

Comment: @ustation3030 awesome! Yeah, `static function` is really just an anonymous function that is specific to that `add_action`. You don't need to create another separate function and pass it to the `add_action` that way. Please upvote answers and select one to mark as accepted. Good luck!